# Cursor inside Trigger not working

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [ddb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[requeststrigger]
ON [dbo].[requests]
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @requestno VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE @statusid INT;
DECLARE thecursor CURSOR FOR SELECT inserted.requestno,contacts.firstname,contacts.lastname,contacts.email FROM request_contacts,contacts,inserted WHERE request_contacts.requestid=inserted.requestid AND contacts.contactid=request_contacts.contactid AND request_contacts.notification=1 AND contacts.notification=1;

SET @statusid = (SELECT statusid FROM inserted);

IF @statusid = 4 AND @statusid <> (SELECT statusid FROM deleted)
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
OPEN thecursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM thecursor
    INTO @requestno,@firstname,@lastname,@email

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        EXEC MAIL_SEND @email,@firstname,@requestno,@lastname;

    FETCH NEXT FROM thecursor
    INTO @requestno,@firstname,@lastname,@email

    END
CLOSE thecursor;

DEALLOCATE thecursor

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

END
```

This simply makes the whole UPDATE/INSERT not work. When I remove the cursor declaration, it works. The cursor is just selecting a field from a table that is existing in the same database called "contacts". What is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Whenever a trigger of TABLE1 is fired (when a row is inserted/updated), I want to jump to TABLE2 another table and get all the records that are associated with that record in TABLE1 (through foreign key) and then loop through those results to call a procedure to do something with them.

Comment: any ideas that can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you prepared to consider amending your design? There appear to be a couple of issues with what you're attempting here.

A trigger isn't necessarily the best place to be doing this kind of row-by-row operation since it executes in-line with the changes to the source table, and will affect the performance of the system negatively.

Also, your existing code evaluates `statusid` only for a single row in the batch, although logically it could be set to more than one value in a single batch of updates.

A more robust approach might be to insert the rows which should generate a `MAIL_SEND` operation to a queuing table, from which a scheduled job can pick rows up and execute `MAIL_SEND`, setting a flag so that each operation is carried out only once.

This would simplify your trigger to an insert - no cursor would be required there (although you will still need a loop of some kind in the sechduled job).