# SQL Trigger Does Not Work When Trying to Have Trigger Send A Email

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to create a database trigger that fires off when a new row is inserted which has a specific word it will send an email alert. The email alert works when I just run that code and the trigger works if I remove the email piece and replace it with something else.

Here is the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER CheckForDirty
ON dbo.Messages
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @MESSAGETEXT varchar(max)
DECLARE @BADWORD1 varchar(50)

SET @MESSAGETEXT = (SELECT Body FROM inserted)
SET @BADWORD1 = 'BadWord'

IF CHARINDEX(@BADWORD1, @MESSAGETEXT) > 0
BEGIN

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='message@email.com',
    @subject = 'Test e-mail sent from database mail',
    @body = 'Someone said something dirty'

END
GO
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360158/cursor-inside-trigger-not-working, although arguably just different enough to avoid a close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be well advised to decouple the email sending code from the trigger - in the trigger, insert the information you need into a "Pending Emails" table. Then create a job that periodically checks the table and send email.

You also need to re-write your trigger to cope with multi-row inserts and updates. `inserted` is a pseudo table that can contain multiple rows.

So I'd write a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckForDirty
ON dbo.Messages
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO PendingEmails (Recipients,Subject,Body)
SELECT 'message@email.com','Test e-mail sent from database mail','Someone said something dirty'
FROM inserted
WHERE CHARINDEX('BadWord',Body) > 0
```

Although I'm assuming that the actual body of the message you're constructing may rely on more info to help identify which message is implicated.

---

Okay, if we're going to build this out into a full example, we'll need to define PendingEmails:

```
CREATE TABLE PendingEmails (
    PendingEmailID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Recipients varchar(max) not null,
    Subject nvarchar(255) not null,
    Body nvarchar(max) not null,
    constraint PK_PendingEmails PRIMARY KEY (PendingEmailID)
)
```

And now we'll write a stored proc that can process pending emails:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DispatchPendingEmails
AS
     declare @PendingEmailID int
     declare @Recipients varchar(max)
     declare @Subject nvarchar(255)
     declare @Body nvarchar(max)

     while exists(select * from PendingEmails)
     begin
         select top 1 @PendingEmailID = PendingEmailID,@Recipients = Recipients,
             @Subject = Subject, @Body = Body from PendingEmails

         exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @Recipients, @subject = @Subject, @body = @Body

         delete from PendingEmails where PendingEmailID = @PendingEmailID
     end
```

And finally, we need to create the job. I'd normally do this through SSMS, but if you want it scripted (you'll need to substitute a different database name in the sp_add_jobstep line, and this is set to run the dispatch every five minutes. All of the stored procs are well documented in MSDN):

```
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'DispatchPendingEmails', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
select @jobId
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N'DispatchPendingEmails', @server_name = N'SYSTEMS86\SQL2K8'
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'DispatchPendingEmails', @step_name=N'ExecSP', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'exec DispatchPendingEmails', 
        @database_name=N'Database', --<-- This needs editing
        @flags=0
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=N'DispatchPendingEmails', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @start_step_id=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_netsend_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_page_operator_name=N''
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @schedule_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=N'DispatchPendingEmails', @name=N'QuiteOften', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=5, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20110218, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT
select @schedule_id
GO
```

Comment: How would I then create a job to send the messages in the table?

Comment: Is it possible to do this with SQL 2008 express or would I need to install SQL 2008 standard?

Comment: @bookbinder - you'd need (at a minimum) workgroup edition, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

First guess would be permissions. When you run the email send manually are you running under a different account than when you execute the trigger? I have seen this before where you test the code under your user account then run an application under a different account that has less permissions. You need to make sure all users are in the correct mail group.

Comment: I run the code under my administrator account. It runs as the default SQL account when it happens for real. How do I change the permissions to get this to work?